# 2 javascript functions clashing?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, time, clock

I am trying to implement a Javascript/PHP/AJAX clock into my website so that I can have a simple clock which can operate in different timezones (tutorial is here http://networking.mydesigntool.com/viewtopic.php?tid=373&id=31)

This itself works fine, but I already have a javascript stopwatch running on the page, and the 2 seem to clash and the clock won't display while the stopwatch is working.

This is the script for the clock:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadTime ()
{
http_request = false;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    // Mozilla, Safari,...
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(http_request.overrideMimeType)
    {
        // set type accordingly to anticipated content type
        //http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        http_request.overrideMimeType('text/html');
    }
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{ // IE
    try
    {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        try
        {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
        }
    }
    }

    var parameters = "time=";
    http_request.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    http_request.open('POST', 'time.php', true);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
    http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http_request.send(parameters);
}


function alertContents()
{
    if (http_request.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (http_request.status == 200)
        {
            result = http_request.responseText;
            document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = result;
        }
    }
}

</script>
<body onload="setInterval('loadTime()', 200);">
```

and this is the code for the stopwatch:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        stopwatch('Start');
    }

    var sec = 0;
    var min = 0;
    var hour = 0;
    function stopwatch(text) {
        sec++;
        if (sec == 60) {
            sec = 0;
            min = min + 1;
        } else {
            min = min;
        }
        if (min == 60) {
            min = 0; 
            hour += 1;
        }

        if (sec<=9) { sec = "0" + sec; }
        document.clock.stwa.value = ((hour<=9) ? "0"+hour : hour) + " : " + ((min<=9) ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec;

        if (text == "Start") { document.clock.theButton.value = "Stop "; }
        if (text == "Stop ") { document.clock.theButton.value = "Start"; }

        if (document.clock.theButton.value == "Start") {
            window.clearTimeout(SD);
            return true;
        }
        SD=window.setTimeout("stopwatch();", 1000);
    }

    function resetIt() {
        sec = -1;
        min = 0;
        hour = 0;
        if (document.clock.theButton.value == "Stop ") {
            document.clock.theButton.value = "Start";
        }
        window.clearTimeout(SD);
    }
</script>
```

Could someone help me get them to work side-by-side please?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, your’re declaring an `onload` event handler in your HTML:

```
<body onload="setInterval('loadTime()', 200);">
```

which is consequently overwritten in script:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    stopwatch('Start');
}
```

This means the original `onload` call is never executed.

You should try using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) so you can add multiple event handlers to the same event.

A couple more points:

- Don’t pass a string to `setInterval` and `setTimeout`, just pass the function itself.  More efficient and less error-prone: `setInterval(loadTime, 200);`
- Instead of writing all that JS code to work with different browsers, use jQuery, mootools, or one of the gazillion other frameworks.  They make it a lot easier to get it right on all browsers.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for your help. Unfortunately I don't know Javascript very well, only the very basics and these scripts were taken from the internet. I posted the same question on another website and someone pointed out the same problems you did and supplied the code to sort it out so it's working now :) Thanks again!

Comment: Hi user, in that case I suggest to start off by following a few good JS tutorials — it really pays of in the long run.  Javascript is very flexible and powerful, but it also makes it incredibly easy to mess things up.

Comment: Hi Martijn, will do. I have bought a book on Javascript/Ajax but the things it goes through don't really apply to the kind of things I would use in the real world. Could you recommend any good tutorials to get started? Thanks

Comment: I’ve found [Javascript: The Good Parts](http://javascript.crockford.com/) to be a real eye-opener (that page also contains a link to the actual book).  It might be a bit advanced, though.  See also the links provided at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info .  And finally, once you’re familiar with the basic concepts, I recommend Mark Pilgrim’s http://diveintohtml5.org for some of the latest and greatest features of web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
See the subtle '+=' instead of '=' !

```
window.onload += function()
{
    stopwatch('Start');
}
```

Comment: Hi Lewis thanks for your reply. I tried changing the line you posted and also the <span id> line to have the id firstClock, but unfortunately the problem is still there. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: I realised that you aren't adding to the onload event - the guy in the following post points it out!

Comment: Thanks Lewis, I've got it sorted now with the help of Martijn and another website :)